# Displaying REST API response as inline pdf (not downloaded file)

Tags: ajax, rest, pdf, content-type

I am using force.com and I have to embed a chatter pdf file inline in the page (not as a download). I have no direct access link to the pdf and the only way to get at the file itself is via a rest call for eg

/services/files/fileid/content

This returns binary pdf data which I then want to embed in the webpage.
Based on various Stack Overflow answers I got some good ideas how to do this and the pdf opens in the page except that its blank - ie it has no content. It has the correct number of pages but no text is displaying.

If I run fiddler while this request is happening, and then save the response as a file the pdf looks great. But for some reason the response coming to the ajax request and being delivered to the browser is no good. I suspect it has something to do with some kind of encoding that I need to be doing in order to properly deliver the pdf data to the browser.

**Would really appreciate any suggestions here or even different approaches - have tried many different ones and this is the closest I got, but am blocked again.**

This is my code making the API call and displaying in the browser:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/services/data/v35.0/chatter/files/069R0000000O8reIAC/content?versionNumber=1",
headers: {"Authorization": "OAuth xxxxxxxxxxxx"},
contentType: "application/pdf",
success: function(data) 
{ 
    
      var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
      window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));     

},
 type: 'GET'
});
```

This opens up a page that looks like this: (note: it has the correct number of pages)
[image]

Even though when I look at fiddler on that request and save the response body as a file the pdf is good!

Comment: Hey, I ran into same problems. Do you happen to know the reason for yours? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include not only the ContentType as "application/pdf", but also to include ContentDisposition as "inline".